# Would having a 10/100 router connected to a gigabit switch for the LAN allow the LAN to be gigabit?

Tags: networking, router, lan, gigabit-ethernet

Ive got a home network that uses cat6 and a managed gigabit switch. The internet line in is c. 45mbps which goes into a 10/100 modem / router combi and then into the gigabit switch.

With the network setout as the diagram below would this enable my local network to be a Gigabit network (as longs as all the connected devices Nas, TVs etc had gigabit ports ?)

Would the local network traffic ever be bottle necked by the 10/100 router or would the local traffic never reach there as it would be routed by the switch.

The reason i havnt changed the router is that if the internet line in is only 45mbps the 10/100 router is more than plenty for it. But at the same time if this could slow down my local network i would update it.

[image: network diagram]

Comment: No;  It would be limited by 10/100 the speed of the LAN ports on the router, everything connected to it would be connected at 10/100/1000 speeds though.  I am guessing that isn't what you want though.

Comment: as long as the router is not used to cross-connect any other devices in the LAN, yes, the LAN will operate at 1gb/s for devices capable of gigabit. if you got a second switch for instance however, plug it into the gigabit switch, not the router, so that the two switches are connected by a full speed link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your internal "LAN" (through the gigabit switch) will communicate at gigabit speed, yes.

Any device requests through the 10/100 switch will be limited to 10/100 - i.e. all Internet "requests".

Your "Internet" traffic will be further limited by your Internet speed (c. 45mbps).